# WordPress: Heavy slow query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In a client website that should display upcoming territory events I got a plugin (called EventsManager), that has been modified to fit our needs.

That plugin, by the way, got an huge query searching for the current events by two parameters, `date_start` and `date_end`.

This query affect only one page, and only one function.

```
$args_filter = $tax_query = array();
$paged = '';

$args_basic = $this->ovaem_query_base($paged, $orderby, $order, $show_past);

switch ($filter) {
[...]
case 'upcomming_showing':
            $args_filter = array(
                'posts_per_page' => $count,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => self::$prefix . '_date_start_time',
                            'value' => current_time('timestamp'),
                            'compare' => '>',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                                'key' => self::$prefix . '_date_start_time',
                                'value' => current_time('timestamp'),
                                'compare' => '<',
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => self::$prefix . '_date_end_time',
                                'value' => current_time('timestamp'),
                                'compare' => '>=',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
            break;
[...]
$args = array_merge_recursive($args_basic, $args_filter, $tax_query);

$eventlist = new WP_Query($args);

return $eventlist;
```

The resultant query, analized with QueryMonitor is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpzt_posts.ID
FROM wpzt_posts
INNER JOIN wpzt_postmeta
ON ( wpzt_posts.ID = wpzt_postmeta.post_id )
INNER JOIN wpzt_postmeta AS mt1
ON ( wpzt_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
INNER JOIN wpzt_postmeta AS mt2
ON ( wpzt_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
INNER JOIN wpzt_postmeta AS mt3
ON ( wpzt_posts.ID = mt3.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wpzt_postmeta.meta_key = 'ovaem_date_start_time'
AND ( ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'ovaem_date_start_time'
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '1643155199'
AND '1643241601' )
OR ( ( mt2.meta_key = 'ovaem_date_start_time'
AND mt2.meta_value < '1643155200' )
AND ( mt3.meta_key = 'ovaem_date_end_time'
AND mt3.meta_value >= '1643155200' ) ) ) ) )
AND wpzt_posts.post_type = 'event'
AND ((wpzt_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wpzt_posts.ID
ORDER BY wpzt_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC
LIMIT 0, 9
```

Using MySQL 5.7 and memcached, this query got **16,69 seconds** to be executed.

Is there a way to optimize that?

Thanks

Comment: you can use Explain to check which part of query taking more time. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: The schema provided by WP is inefficient.  This plugin should help your query quite a bit:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Answer (score 0):

How the query comes out of set of code is unclear.  But a direct query (inserting your parameters as applicable) could be simplified to

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
        p.ID
    FROM 
        wpzt_posts p
            JOIN wpzt_postmeta mtStart
                ON p.ID = mtStart.post_id
                AND mtStart.meta_key = 'ovaem_date_start_time'
            LEFT JOIN wpzt_postmeta mtEnd
                ON p.ID = mtEnd.post_id
                AND mtEnd.meta_key = 'ovaem_date_end_time'
                AND mtEnd.meta_value >= '1643155200'
    WHERE 
            p.post_type = 'event'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND ( 
                mtStart.meta_value BETWEEN '1643155199' AND '1643241601' 
            OR ( mtStart.meta_value < '1643155200' 
                AND mtEnd.meta_value > '1643155200'
            ) 
    GROUP BY 
        p.ID
    ORDER BY 
        mtStart.meta_value + 0 ASC
    LIMIT 
        0, 9
```

So, not knowing specifically about WordPress and how you have it configured, Does your data allow for multiple start and end time entries for a SINGLE POST ID?  If so, that will result in a Cartesian Result thus over multiplying the instances.

Are you trying to count how many UNIQUE Post IDs are found, or total records found for all the meta-data entries associated with said posts.

For indexes, I would suggest having the following

```
Table        Index on
wpzt_posts   ( post_type, post_status, id )
wpzt_postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
```

I removed the `CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED)` since the records associated with date/time context will always be numeric, its not like you would ever encounter a time of 'this is bad data' and thus influence a bad numeric conversion.  As such, the function call makes it non-sargeable and thus will not utilize an index.  But if all instances of a start/end time are all digits, you wont have that confusion -- unless the physical lengths of those numeric representations actually are longer or shorter, but even in that case, a smaller number would probably indicate a date sooooo far back, it would not even be in the range being considered and thus no impact.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. Datas don't allow multiple start and end time, it's just like a search. Indexes are already set as you suggest, sorry if I don't clarify. By the way I can't define an arbitrary query, so I need to work with WP_Query()